# Unable to download Images from Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download the profile picture from firebase whose name is set as the userID of the user. I am using the glide library to download the images but I am getting a `StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location.` error.

Here is my code

```
String uid = user.getUid();

            storageReference.child("ProfilePictures").child(uid).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                    Log.d("TAG" , "URI = "+uri);

                    GlideApp.with(context).load(uri).into(profilepic);
                    //profilepic.setImageURI(uri);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error getting Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

    });
```

My Database
[image]

[image]

Declaration of storageReference

```
StorageReference storageReference;

storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: are you getting this log `Log.d("TAG" , "URI = "+uri);`?

Comment: No the app crashes

Comment: Try `.child(uid + ".jpg")`

Comment: Try using `child()` single time, like this: `.child("ProfilePictures/" + uid + ".jpg")`.

Comment: Show the structure of ProfilePictures folder pls!

Comment: @PrajwalW as you can see his 1st picture it's properly shown that image available in folder

Comment: Then y is  the need of using .child(uid) ???

Comment: @PrajwalW that's why i posted answer with changes

Comment: @PrajwalW Because the picture name is same as uid of the user I changed it uid.jpg in the code but no change

Comment: Did the answer of @PeterHaddad helped u???

Comment: @PrajwalW No, it didnt

Comment: can you post the declaration of storageReference cause i am thinking you already provided child there that's why it's showing file not available

Comment: @PrajwalW yes it did :p

Comment: might you're declaration and storage reference query conflict and create new query which is looking for you're file in `ProfilePictures/ProfilePictures/uid.jpg`

Comment: Sorry for being private but can i ask what rules you have set to you're firebase storage ?

Comment: @Ashish Since Im still developing the app , all the permissions are public in storage and database

Comment: Are you able to access any other file from FirebaseStorage?

Comment: On other activities I am able to download/upload files to all the folders shown

Comment: @DarrylFernandes did my answer solve the issue?

Comment: @PeterHaddad  it did solve the error but now glide is giving some bizarre errors

Comment: @DarrylFernandes since my answer solved your problem, please upvote it and mark it as correct so other users know it is helpful thank you

Comment: @DarrylFernandes was your problem solved???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
storageReference.child("ProfilePictures").child(uid).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
```

into this:

```
storageReference.child("ProfilePictures").child(uid + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
```

Comment: are u sure the `uid` exists in the database? Did you try and hardcode it inside the `child(.......)`?

Comment: `D/TAG: UID = 5tI5e4Y2NeOQ7yq8DwefvmYJk713` uid in logcat

Comment: no I mean inside the `child()`, `storageReference.child("ProfilePictures").child('5tI5e4Y2NeOQ7yq8DwefvmYJk713.jpg')`

Comment: Tried this also. No change

Comment: @DarrylFernandes hi in the comment here `D/TAG: UID = 5tI5e4Y2NeOQ7yq8DwefvmYJk713 uid in logcat` how did u enter inside `onSuccess`???

Answer (score 2):

```
 public StorageReference mStorageRef;
 StorageReference particular_image;

 private FirebaseDatabase firebasedatabase;
 private DatabaseReference databasereference;

 oncreate()
   {
     mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("give");
     firebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();  //1st time is imp.
     databasereference = firebasedatabase.getReference().child("giver_data"); 

      particular_image.putFile(photoURI).addOnSuccessListener
                (this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        final Uri download_uri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(p_l.getPhotoUrl()).asBitmap().override(view.getMaxWidth(),view.getMaxHeight()).error(R.drawable.ic_selfie_point_icon)   //asbitmap after load always.
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(resource).getBitmap();
                        int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                        //holder.food_img.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                        view.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    }
                });
                   //getting uri of the image stored
                      //Photo_link p_link =newPhoto_link(download_uri.toString());
                     //  databasereference.push().setValue(p_link);
                        //String uri_string = download_uri.toString();

                        pb.clearAnimation();
                        pb.clearFocus();
                       // animation.end();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Giver_Edit.class);
                        i.setData(download_uri);
                        startActivity(i);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Food Image Uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.d("giver_image_success","no eroooooor_on_success");
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


        //  final Uri selectedImgUri = getIntent().getData();


        particular_image.putFile(uri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("giver_image_failure","eroooooor_on_ffailure");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And now this should solve your problem! Make sure to upvote if helpful and comment if doubt!
**Note:** Instead of my code function of UploadTask use your onSuccess() which you had mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if you're allowed to users to access Storage with this Rule :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Put this in you're dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1'
}
```

Now Get Image from storage :

```
StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProfilePictures/"+uid+".jpg"); // if you know how to use this you can get image directly without doing that big query

//Following line will be useful when you try to get image from storage
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

For further information you can read [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) or just comment me if any issue occur

Comment: what is problem with this can you tell me i'll help you with it

Comment: `E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.` Im getting this same error

Comment: @DarrylFernandes same problem with my method ? if that's the problem with it then i think you recheck the storage cause i think file name changed or something else

Comment: I just checked it again. Its there

Comment: The problem is if u want to load the image in your app, to need to retrieve it as a Uri and then extract the Uri by using getdownloadurl() function.

Comment: @PrajwalW i don't think he wants to download he just want to set the image to profile or somewhere the above method is better but something wrong with his project

Comment: To load the image in your app to need to access your image by downlading it as a url....like the image stored on the firebase is a Url and not an actual image and thus u need to access it by retrieving the url . Thats the actual way of accessing and retrieving the image in your app

Comment: @PrajwalW if you read about [FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) you will understand to proper process how it will be done without using download uri

Comment: I prefer Glide rather than GlideApp

Comment: @Ashish the link u provided refers to Google Cloud Storage and not Firebase Storage! The question is about Firebase Storage!